# Newbie Needs Direction - Monitor contents of variable in a seperate process

Tags: c++, process, automation, hook, monitor

I want to apologize up front for being unfamiliar with the terminology I should use.  I have programming experience, but not in this area.  I'm looking for general guidance, links to helpful sources, books, ect that will help me understand my problem better and can possible give a tutorial on how to achieve a solution.

On the surface, I think what I am trying to do is pretty simple, it's just I have never done any programming with hooking other applications.

## The Goal:

## I am trying to monitor (not change) a variable (or a few variables) in a game.  In the UI of the game, there is a box that lists some items in plain text. I want to know what items that box contains.  I would like a function in my code that returns the contents of that box as a string.  This could be done with OCR, but I was thinking this may be a better, faster, more accurate solution. Plus, OCR isn't a simple solution either.

I will likely be writing my program in C++, since it seems like that would be the best language for my overall project (of which, this is just a small, but important part).

I would appreciate your thoughts or suggestions on the best way to achieve this. Especially any references that may help me to create such a function.

Thank you.

Comment: Forget OCR immediately for that purpose, then google for "game trainer", ReadProcessMemory (Windows) etc.etc.

Comment: Won't the address of that information change potentially each time i launch the game?

Comment: Not necessarily, because of the virtual address layer of modern OS. (But some situations could lead to such changes, especially game code written with this purpose in mind so that cheating becomes harder)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a "monitoring" task that goes through the variables and sends events to a container of recipients.  The frequency would be adjustable via sleep command.

You could also use an `std::bitset` to indicate whether the variable's value has changed since the last notification and only notify recipients of the changed variables.

Research "subscriber design pattern" and "publisher design pattern".